# Error when executing command - 'npm install bcryptjs jsonwebtoken'

Tags: mongodb, jwt, mern, web-development-server, react-fullstack

I tried to `install bcryptjs jsonwebtoken` but encountered an error.

In addition, another error arose when I tried `npm install mongodb`.

```
npm install bcryptjs jsonwebtoken
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-palette@1.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"^1.9.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@13.4.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.22.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/next-auth
npm ERR!       next-auth@"^4.22.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer next@">=9.0.0" from next-pwa@5.6.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/next-pwa
npm ERR!       next-pwa@"^5.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   11 more (next-auth, react-dom, react-hot-toast, react-icons, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.6" from react-palette@1.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-palette
npm ERR!   react-palette@"^1.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.6" from react-palette@1.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-palette
npm ERR!     react-palette@"^1.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\sanjj\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-17T04_36_27_862Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sanjj\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-17T04_36_27_862Z-debug-0.log
```

Any advice for these errors would be appreciated.